# Classic ASP Session Resetting when too busy?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp-classic

It appears that when there are more than enough users signed in the sessions get reset in my Classic ASP application.. Why do you think this is?

The Application pool was set to Classic instead of Integrated, not sure if this has any affect on it?

I'm looking everywhere and cannot find what may be causing it.  I set recycling in the app pool to OFF, and it still does a session reset, people are saying when it's busy usually.. So that means something.. Anyone?

There are other sites in the webserver, and the only thing in the event log shows this around the same time:

> A worker process with process id of '6120' serving application pool '...' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed.

Do these other sites affect the session reset problem i'm encountering?

Comment: Have you verified that your ASP[.NET?] sites are actually assigned to the application pools that you think they are?

Comment: There is only 1 .net site, it is actually an application that exists inside the site being session reset constantly.

Comment: Are you just using the DefaultAppPool or is it in a separate pool?

Comment: The .net application within the classic asp site causing the session resets is in the same application pool as the classic asp site, should it be a seperate application pool?  is this causing the session resets in the classic asp site?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with them co-existing, unless one of them is doing something to force the session states to reset (or if the asp.net site crashes, it could force the worker process to recycle).  So it couldn't hurt to swap them into separate process to see if that helps.

Comment: the .net site wasn't being used when the session reset was occuring, so i doubt it has anything to do with that.. additionally, i turn off the recycling in the apppool for the site in classic asp, therefore, the .net site also inherits it since its in the same app pool.. I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the COM+ objects i'm using, how do i see if the COM+ objects are causing this reset?

Comment: Do you think it has anything to do with RestartOnConfigChange=True ?
this started happening after i updated the service pack .

Comment: `RestartOnConfigChange` can affect the .net site, shouldn't affect the classic asp site.  Again though; if you made a change to the .net site and it's in the same worker process, then it would recycle the worker process (causing the session reset in the classic asp)

Comment: This is in IIS > ASP settings, for global.asa i believe, but global.asa isn't being updated, so not sure this is causing it.

Comment: how do i catch the event causing the reset?

Comment: Unless it makes an event log entry, you probably can't.  You can turn on _all_ the logging options in IIS, but I don't think that is going to give you any information either.  This is one of those things that is very difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: The only log entry is another application pool going inactive, for another website on the server..